# Error Code after trying to instal your Ubuntu Desktop Download on VirtualBox for MAC

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, system

As i said in the object, I cannot install the your Ubuntu Desktop ISO Download file on VirtualBox with MAC. 
I created the new environment to setup the Linux operating system on VirtualBox with normal specs (1024 Mo ; 10 GB ; Dinamic Disks ; ..) but when I try to run this new environment for the first time to put the Ubuntu ISO inside i get this error message :

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
MediumWrap
IMedium {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}
IVirtualBox {d0a0163f-e254-4e5b-a1f2-011cf991c38d}
VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

Can you please help me to solve this problem?
Thanks for your help i'm learning but already stuck !

Franckay

Answer (score 1):

Open the Virtual Media Manager and fix the path for the iso you downloaded, it seems you moved the iso from the original location it was at when you added it in virtualbox. In the Virtual Media Manager you should see an object marked as missing, delete it and re-add the iso from its new location.